Programmatically get information on a packaged Connected App
I have a connected app packaged in a 2GP. Ideally, I wanted to update information (client credential user) on it but I'm fine with just detecting whether this param is present and having it manually set by the package user. However, when I run the code that calls the Metadata API to get the info, in my development scratch org it does return the info on the Connected App, but in a subscriber org the API returns an UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION. Any suggestions?
public with sharing class MetadataApi {
    // This worked in a dev scratch org but in a subscriber org returns an unknown exception
    public static String queryMetadataApi(String body) {
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setEndpoint(
            Url.getOrgDomainUrl().toExternalForm() + '/services/Soap/m/60.0'
        );
        req.setMethod('POST');
        req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
        req.setHeader('SOAPAction', '""');
        req.setBody(body);
        HttpResponse r = new Http().send(req);
        return r.getBody().toString();
    }

    public static String genGetConnectedAppXml() {
        return '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>' +
            '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">' +
            '   <soapenv:Header>' +
            '      <SessionHeader>' +
            '         <sessionId>' +
           getSessionId() +
            '</sessionId>' +
            '      </SessionHeader>' +
            '   </soapenv:Header>' +
            '   <soapenv:Body>' +
            '      <readMetadata>' +
            '         <type>ConnectedApp</type>' +
            '         <fullNames>namespace__ConnectedAppName</fullNames>' +
            '      </readMetadata>' +
            '   </soapenv:Body>' +
            '</soapenv:Envelope>';
    }

    private static String getSessionId() {
        String content = Page.namespace__SessionID.getContent().toString();
        Integer s = content.indexOf('###start###') + '###start###'.length();
        Integer e = content.indexOf('###end###');
        return content.substring(s, e);
    }
}

What I see it return:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:sf="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata"><soapenv:Body><soapenv:Fault><faultcode>sf:UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION</faultcode><faultstring>UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION: An unexpected error occurred. Please include this ErrorId if you contact support: 1631859509-66175 (-1863924034)</faultstring></soapenv:Fault&

